# Android App Crashes Suddenly while running?

Tags: android, android-ndk

**What my App does ?**
The App I am developing is a typical client server App which talks to a windows server using Wifi. The Application has multiple Activities and really has heavy memory and CPU requirements i.e native calls for speex encoding / decoding.

**What my Problem is ?**
The problem is the Application restarts suddenly while working absolutely fine. Sometimes while working normally suddenly I see (in logcat ) that the Constructor of Application class (Class which extends API's Application Class) is called. That crashes my App since all the global data is stored with in the Application class itself.

**What I have done ?**
The first thing which struck my mind was that may be Android feels their is low memory so it terminates my App, and than restarts it automatically. So I implemented `onLowMemory()` of Application class. But to my surprise it is never called..

**What is the main problem ?** The main problem is that `Nothing is printed on LogCat`. It looks that even the Android itself is clueless about why it restarted my already running Application ?

What could be the possible reason of this sudden restart ? How can I avoid that ?

I am working on Galaxy Y, and the API version is 2.3.6. My AndroidManifiest.xml looks like

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="some.package.MyApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="15"
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:name="some.package.MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/display_image"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="some.package.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="user" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="some.package.BuddyListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="user"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

            <!--
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="some.package.SessionWindowActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="user"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

            <!--
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT**
I just saw following output in LogCat after using CheckJNI,

```
06-26 17:27:30.023: I/remove(24544): Sending Signal : 13 **//App Working fine here**
06-26 17:27:32.148: D/dalvikvm(24544): GC_CONCURRENT freed 446K, 49% free 3384K/6599K, external 1057K/1076K, paused 3ms+4ms
06-26 17:27:39.531: W/dalvikvm(24544): **HeapWorker may be wedged: 7374ms spent** inside LsomePackageName/modules/AudioPlayer;.finalize()V
06-26 17:27:40.023: I/remove(24544): Sending Signal : 13
06-26 17:27:40.218: D/dalvikvm(24544): GC_CONCURRENT freed 479K, 49% free 3383K/6599K, external 1057K/1076K, paused 9ms+5ms 
06-26 17:27:42.343: E/RoobrooApp(24670): Application Instance created **//Restarted** 
06-26 17:27:42.351: I/ApplicationPackageManager(24670): cscCountry is not German : INS
```

**UPDATE**
While experimenting further at one step I intentionally allocated a very large memory for a double array. But to my surprise neither **onLowMemory()** called nor the App restarted instead I got outOfMemoryException. If onLowMemory() is never called why it is there ?

One more problem is that after restart OS already starts BuddyListActivity instead of LoginActivity... Help really needed ....

**UPDATE 2**
I just saw following error log, I really don't know what that means..

```
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308): ReferenceTable overflow (max=1024)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308): Last 10 entries in JNI pinned array reference table:
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1014: 0x405b0280 cls=[B (340 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1015: 0x405b03d8 cls=[S (660 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1016: 0x405d8208 cls=[B (340 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1017: 0x405d8360 cls=[S (660 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1018: 0x405f8b08 cls=[B (340 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1019: 0x405f8c60 cls=[S (660 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1020: 0x405f8ef8 cls=[B (340 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1021: 0x405ff698 cls=[S (660 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1022: 0x405f9050 cls=[B (340 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):  1023: 0x405ff930 cls=[S (660 bytes)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308): JNI pinned array reference table summary (1024 entries):
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):     1 of [B 20B
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):   508 of [B 340B (508 unique)
06-29 12:07:28.398: W/dalvikvm(19308):     3 of [B 348B (3 unique)
06-29 12:07:28.406: W/dalvikvm(19308):   511 of [S 660B (511 unique)
06-29 12:07:28.406: W/dalvikvm(19308):     1 of [S 668B
06-29 12:07:28.406: W/dalvikvm(19308): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 511712 bytes
06-29 12:07:28.406: E/dalvikvm(19308): Failed adding to JNI pinned array ref table (1024 entries)
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308): "Thread-14" prio=5 tid=12 RUNNABLE
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050e548 self=0x2240b8
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | sysTid=19953 nice=-19 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1905240
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | schedstat=( 207153329 82244881 1015 )
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at some.package.MyApp.speex.SpeexEncoder.encode(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at some.package.MyApp.speex.SpeexEncoder.encodeFrame(SpeexEncoder.java:51)
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at some.package.MyApp.models.Session.capturedAudioReceived(Session.java:656)
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at some.package.MyApp.modules.AudioCapturer.run(AudioCapturer.java:118)
06-29 12:07:28.406: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-29 12:07:28.406: E/dalvikvm(19308): VM aborting
06-29 12:07:29.726: W/AudioTrack(19308): obtainBuffer() track 0x1d3520 disabled, restarting
06-29 12:07:30.351: W/dalvikvm(19308): threadid=4: spin on suspend #1 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
06-29 12:07:30.898: W/AudioTrack(19308): obtainBuffer() track 0x1d3520 disabled, restarting
06-29 12:07:31.101: W/dalvikvm(19308): threadid=4: spin on suspend #2 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510490 self=0x159898
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | sysTid=19312 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1575600
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | schedstat=( 1556395 4913328 26 )
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40022198 self=0xcec8
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | sysTid=19308 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1345006496
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | schedstat=( 5364166234 3306213349 13647 )
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.media.AudioTrack.native_write_short(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.media.AudioTrack.write(AudioTrack.java:943)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at some.package.MyApp.modules.AudioPlayer.onPeriodicNotification(AudioPlayer.java:163)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.media.AudioTrack$NativeEventHandlerDelegate$1.handleMessage(AudioTrack.java:1084)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-29 12:07:31.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:31.851: W/dalvikvm(19308): threadid=4: spin on suspend #3 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510490 self=0x159898
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | sysTid=19312 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1575600
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | schedstat=( 2868652 6927485 37 )
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40022198 self=0xcec8
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | sysTid=19308 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1345006496
06-29 12:07:31.851: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | schedstat=( 5364166234 3306213349 13647 )
06-29 12:07:32.000: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.media.AudioTrack.native_write_short(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:32.015: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.media.AudioTrack.write(AudioTrack.java:943)
06-29 12:07:32.031: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at some.package.MyApp.modules.AudioPlayer.onPeriodicNotification(AudioPlayer.java:163)
06-29 12:07:32.039: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.media.AudioTrack$NativeEventHandlerDelegate$1.handleMessage(AudioTrack.java:1084)
06-29 12:07:32.054: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 12:07:32.054: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-29 12:07:32.062: W/AudioTrack(19308): obtainBuffer() track 0x1d3520 disabled, restarting
06-29 12:07:32.070: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-29 12:07:32.093: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:32.101: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-29 12:07:32.109: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-29 12:07:32.125: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-29 12:07:32.132: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:32.890: W/dalvikvm(19308): threadid=4: spin on suspend #4 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
06-29 12:07:32.890: I/dalvikvm(19308): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
06-29 12:07:32.890: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510490 self=0x159898
06-29 12:07:32.890: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | sysTid=19312 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1575600
06-29 12:07:32.890: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | schedstat=( 5340582 316192616 59 )
06-29 12:07:32.898: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:32.898: I/dalvikvm(19308): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
06-29 12:07:32.898: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40022198 self=0xcec8
06-29 12:07:32.898: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | sysTid=19308 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1345006496
06-29 12:07:32.898: I/dalvikvm(19308):   | schedstat=( 5364166234 3306213349 13647 )
06-29 12:07:32.929: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.media.AudioTrack.native_write_short(Native Method)
06-29 12:07:32.945: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at android.media.AudioTrack.write(AudioTrack.java:943)
06-29 12:07:32.953: I/dalvikvm(19308):   at some.package.MyApp.modules.AudioPlayer.onPeriodicNotification(AudioPlayer.java:163)
```

**Solution**
Well the testing is still on for the changed code and everything seems positive so far.. The problem was inside JNI (I guess). @n.Collins statement **"The fact that no error is reported by the JVM also indicates it caused by your native code."** Was one of the most correct pointers towards the solution. I really thank all the people who answered it really helped me in some way or the other. I actually removed a set of other bugs while trying to solve this problem all thanks to the community.

Comment: I understand that onLowMemory is not being called; however, have you tried monitoring your memory usage looking for memory leaks?

Additionally, are you certain nothing is printed to logcat. I only ask as filtering for your application tag may actually prevent seeing all applicable crash messages. Make sure you are looking at an unfiltered logcat view during a crash.

Comment: `onLowMemory()` isn't guaranteed to get called according to the docs. I observered that `OutOfMemoryErrors` inside native(and maybe inside Java) Code could lead to Application crashes without any Message or Log.

Comment: @tencent I have cross checked LogCat filtering.. I am looking at correctly.. Nothing is printed in LogCat notifying me about the crash.. Application runs normally and suddenly line inside Application Constructor is printed... Which indicates that app has just restarted without telling you any reason...

Comment: @RafaelT. I have checked the Allocation Tracker and Heap View of DDMS... The total memory usage never crosses more than 53% of allocated heap..

Comment: Native code allocations aren't always reliably tracked by those DDMS views pre-Android 3.0.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in jni. You might want to consider adding more debug symbols in jni. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/y8lrC_t56cQ.

Comment: also, should you start a diffrent question regarding your last issue? that your os starts the second Activity, instead of the LoginActivity?

Comment: @BinoyBabu How do I find if their is some problem in JNI ?

Comment: `onLowMemory()` is called when the *device* is low on memory, not your individual process.

Comment: regarding your last question, regarding not starting with your LAUNCHER Activity, you can check my question here. I had a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243019/application-restart-activity-entry-point

Comment: How are you getting the logcat? Using eclipse? adb? ddms? I find it incredibly hard to believe that you don't see any messages. Usually if your process dies and there are activities in it you will see WINDOW DEATH messages and there are usually others as well. Anyway, it is pretty clear that your process is crashing and the OS is automatically restarting it. When it does that it removes the top activity from the stack because it assumes it is responsible for the crash and restarts the activity that was underneath that in the stack.

Comment: I doubt, the Problem is in Android OS not in the Project.

Comment: I am using eclipse logcat to view. I tried DDMS but it also restarts (clears all the data in its views) suddenly. I tried debugging but since it is multi threaded program its hard to trace where the problem occurred..

Comment: @MKJParekh, Why you said that ? Are their any chances for that.. I will be really thankful to you if you elaborate more on it... Thanks

Comment: Come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Update #2, it is pretty clear that you have failed to unpin an array in your JNI.  This means that you are using the `Get<Type>ArrayElements` and have failed to match 1 or more of these calls with `Release<Type>ArrayElements`.

As a result, the ReferenceTable is overflowing.  Look for places where you are calling Get and not calling Release.  For example you could be calling `GetIntArrayElements` but failing to call `ReleaseIntArrayElements` when you are finished.

Comment: I cross checked my JNI code it seems correct, APP still crashes but I haven't got that error before.

Answer (score 19):

It is hard to tell without complete source code exactly what is happening, but perhaps Romain Guy's answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/G_ngkPTOfRo) on Google Groups will help.

> `onLowMemory()`is called when the entire system is running out of
>   memory, not when your process is running out of memory. Each app is
>   limited to a fixed amount of RAM (24 MB on a Nexus One for instance).
>   If you use up these 24 MB but the system still has more RAM available,
>   you will get an`OutOfMemoryError`but not`onLowMemory()`.

The 24mb limit is pretty much set in stone for applications on < Honeycomb. If you are targeting API 11 or higher you can ask for more memory by declaring that a large heap be allocated for your application. It is not mentioned in documentation but adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to your `application` tag in your Manifest.xml will do this (although it is not guaranteed).

Note: on modified firmware (custom ROMs) it is possible for that value to be lower or higher. I believe on the Samsung Galaxy Nexus it is 48mb by default, but as a general rule staying within 24mb is a safe assumption. There is also a [great post](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2012/03/30/learn-about-the-technical-differences-between-gingerbread-and-ics/) on the Sony Ericsson explaining the technical differences between Gingerbread and Ice Cream Sandwich (RAM is a topic covered in-depth).

Good luck, I hope this at least helps you track down the issue.

Comment: I just read few blogs and saw Google IO 2011 Video Session on Memory Issue for Android.. learned and Solved few leaks.. but the problem is still their ...

Comment: @anDroider It is difficult to tell without your source code what the problem is, but all signs point to some sort of performance issue. If you tried it on a higher-end device running API 11 or higher with largeHeap="true" are these results the same? That, or add some log calls in your native code and see where those stop. Perhaps you have some infinite recursion or loop or memory leak you are unaware of.

Comment: It's 16mb on the Nexus one, I use:
long heap = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1024; 
On apps what allow users to keep loading pictures to stop them before heap gets too close to 16mb, and also keep sending that number to logcat to help debug leaky apps.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSykes that's definitely helpful for RAM-intensive applications. I'm sure it changes from device to device, some like the new Samsung Galaxy S3 would probably allow 24mb if not 48mb, especially when using largeHeap="true".

Answer (score 6):

The other posters have covered the out-of-memory issues.  I'll just add that to debug your native code, one quick-and-dirty way is to add log messages at various checkpoints.  Here's an example from one of my native cpp files:

```
#include <android/log.h>

...

// Set to 1 to enable debug log traces...
#define DEBUG  0

#define LOG_TAG         "yourNativeCodeLogTag"
#if DEBUG
#define LOG_ERROR(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_WARN(...)   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_INFO(...)   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_DEBUG(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#else // if !DEBUG
#define LOG_ERROR(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_WARN(...)   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_INFO(...)   
#define LOG_DEBUG(...) 
#endif // DEBUG

...

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_whatever_package_YourClassName_jniInitializeLibrary(JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, /* other irrelevant stuff here */)                 
{    
    LOG_DEBUG("Initializing native library.\n");
    ....
}
```

Finally, you will also need to add `-llog` to your LOCAL_LDLIBS variable in the relevant `*.mk` file.  Then, you can get log messages from your native library in logcat.

UPDATE:  After seeing your updates, I think you should use the above technique to pepper log messages into your native `encode()` method to see exactly where it's crashes.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough rep to comment on other people's answers, but I think [Error 454's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288397/904134) is pretty close.

I had a similar problem with my own app with application restarting with no message. My problem was caused by an array overflow where I was trying to access index `n+1` in an array of `n` objects in my native code. The fact that no error is reported by the JVM also indicates it caused by your native code.

This question: [c++ Jni Reference Table overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959495/jni-reference-table-overflow) has a very similar error log to your update 2, further indicating that your error lies in not having matched your get and release calls.

If you don't understand what the `JNI pinned reference table` is, I'd like to direct your attention to the [JNI Specification sections titled "Accessing Java Objects", and the following section "Accessing Primitive Arrays"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp1253).

Finally, some snippets of your native code where you access primitive data arrays would be useful to help solve your problem, but in the meantime I'd like draw your attention to the final comment on the answer to [ReferenceTable overflow (max=512) JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372373/referencetable-overflow-max-512-jni) which reads:

> `GetObjectArrayElement` returns object with local reference on it, so you need to delete local reference. But you should do that only when you are done with array elements. So you should put `DeleteLocalRef(oneDim)` after `releaseIntArrayElements(oneDim)`.

So please, *double check that you have matched Get/Release calls* when you access your array elements and, when you no longer need access to it, *delete the local reference*. It is possible that you are hitting the end of the JNI pinned reference table because you are not deleting old objects. Remember, JNI is just a c interface for Java, so you have to help out the garbage collection for your native code.

Comment: When I tried DeleteLocalRef after Relese<type>ArrayElements I got several `JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x40536dc8) failed to find entry (valid=0)` messages and the application got crashed...

Comment: I don't use GetObjectArrayElement() instead I use GetByteArrayElement and GetShortArrayElement and the Release methods for them... Do I still need DeleteLocalRef... if not than how to delete the memory occupied by array references (if any ) ?

Comment: What value are you using for the `mode` argument in your `Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements` call? We can't really help much more without seeing some of your native code. A snippet showing where how you are using the get/release methods and what you do with the data in-between would be useful.

Comment: Actually I got confidence by reading your statement "If the App crashes and doesn't tell anything it means it is because of some error in JNI".... Than I further debugged and read more about Speex Audio Decoding... It turned out that one of the speex's function was returning unexpected value sometimes.. I corrected the code  and so far it has not crashed... thanks I have also edited the question to mention your name in it... Have a nice day...

Comment: @Amit You stated getting JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x40536dc8) failed to find entry (valid=0) when using Release...ArrayElements. That is the same I get. I also use Speex, so we had the same error in code ;) - when I introduced the release code round about a year ago, my crashes disappeared, but now I get these annoying Log messages on every Speex frame. Did you get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

One thing that can be the problem, is that maybe your app crashes somewhere inside the `native code` and this will suddenly stop your app without any message, and nothing printed in the `Logcat`.

I had the same problem, while trying to decode some `bitmaps`, android crashed somewhere inside `native code` and the app stops, without displaying any message.

Regarding `onLowMemory()` @Tom answers covers it.

Comment: How do I find that their is some crash in native code ? How you did that ?

Comment: I really don't know how you can debug the native code... I think you'll need to add some logs from native code. Me, I just saw some weird errors in the logcat.