# Android - restoring state when process has been killed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity with fragments in Android, and if I minimize the app and after a while the system kills the process, later when I run the app it crashes, because it tries to resume from the second activity (the one with fragments), even though the process has been killed and it is NOT a launcher activity.
The reason it crashes is because in the fragments some view use variables from a Singleton class, and when the process is killed all those variables become null.
So I tried with a check in the parent activity that hosts the fragments like this

```
public class SecondActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    FragmentTabsAdapter tabsAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Crash", "Second Activity");
        if (Commons.INST.someVariableFromTheSingleton == null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
                        // Splash screen is the launcher activity
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
            tabsAdapter = new FragmentTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when it tries to restore the activity even though I explicitly stated to start the launcher activity, it still proceeds with this second activity lifecycle methods.... How do I stop it once it starts the intent?

Comment: Maybe this [similar link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11243019/1051783) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) with an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class for your singleton.  From the android documents,

> You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans,
>   floats, ints, longs, and strings.  This data will persist across user
>   sessions (even if your application is killed).

Comment: The point is I dont want to keep those variable, but to restart the app if the process has been killed

Answer (score 0):

Try to call finish() after startActivity(i)

Comment: still nothing, even tried with super.finish() and it still continues with the lifecycle methods and even goes to the fragment code

Answer (score 0):

Does the SecondActivity activity have intent filter MAIN in AndroidManifest.xml as shown below

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
```

if it does try to remove this filter.

Comment: no, the other activities have this
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
and even though only the SplashScreen has LAUNCHER, this problem occurs

Comment: than try to add "android.intent.action.MAIN" to SplashScreen itent filter. System will start SplashScreen acrivity instead.
I dealt with such issue a long time ago, and if I remember correctly I had fixed it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` you want to do this:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
                    // Splash screen is the launcher activity
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        return;
```

This will only work if `SplashScreen` is still at the root of the activity stack (ie: it hasn't been finished). If you are currently calling `finish()` in `SplashScreen` when it launches the next Activity, you'll need to remove that so that you always have `SplashScreen` as the root of the Activity stack. To prevent the user from pressing BACK and going back into `SplashScreen` you should set a boolean flag in `SplashScreen` when it has launched the next Activity, and in `SplashScreen.onResume()` you should check this boolean flag and call `finish()` if the flag is set (this will then "exit" your application).