# Strip Android NDK Logging

Tags: logging, android-ndk

Is there any easy and straight way to strip-out all the logging calls in NDK when in release mode?

Comment: This is what I do:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190469/android-app-crashes-suddenly-while-running/11271063#11271063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025764/78496 for how to do it on iOS. The principle is the same.

You can set a flag in your Makefile using

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DDEBUG_ON
```